# Searching for files on SMB share shows all files as question marks "?" on macOS High Sierra

Tags: finder, high-sierra, search, smb

Searching on SMB share in Finder on macOS High Sierra (10.13.3) shows all files names as "?". The correct kind and size is identified, it is just the name that is messed up.

Browsing works fine and all files show up correctly.

It worked fine on Sierra before upgrading to High Sierra.

Also the "kind" suddenly contains Japanese(?) letters. Doesn't usually show. The system language is English.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

[image: Search SMB on macOS High Sierra]

Comment: What type of SMB server? Is it a Windows system, a NAS or a Unix system running Samba?

Comment: It's on a Windows server. I don't know the specifics of it. Last night I did a clean install of High Sierra and it all seems to be working now.

Answer (score 1):

I did a clean install of High Sierra and it's working now. I guess some system files had been corrupted during the upgrade.

Not really a fix, so if someone has a better answer I'll hapily give them the points. I consider it closed for now.